# Is it possible to use layers and effect together in Direct2d? If so, can you give an example?

Tags: direct2d

Is it possible to use layers and effect together in Direct2d? If so, can you give an example?
I have not found a good example.
Using layers could allow applying effects to a group of drawn objects.
In certain areas, direct2d seems to be underdocumented.

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Is it possible to…” a poorly worded question?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7273).
Please show your attempts you have tried and the problems/error messages you get from your attempts.
It is unclear what you are asking or what the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course it's possible, as the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct2d/direct2d-layers-overview#what-are-layers) says:

> You use a layer by "pushing" it onto a render target. Subsequent
> drawing operations by the render target are directed to the layer

Here is some demo code (no error check for brevity):

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <wrl.h>
#include <d2d1.h>
#include <d2d1_1.h>
#include <d2d1effects.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "d2d1")
#pragma comment(lib, "dxguid")

using namespace Microsoft::WRL;

ComPtr<ID2D1SolidColorBrush> colorBrush;
ComPtr<ID2D1HwndRenderTarget> renderTarget;
ComPtr<ID2D1DeviceContext> deviceContext;
ComPtr<ID2D1Effect> effect;

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_PAINT:
    {
        renderTarget->BeginDraw();
        renderTarget->Clear(D2D1::ColorF(D2D1::ColorF::Black));

        // create & push layer
        ComPtr<ID2D1Layer> layer;
        auto hr = renderTarget->CreateLayer(nullptr, layer.GetAddressOf());
        RECT rc; GetClientRect(hwnd, &rc);
        renderTarget->PushLayer(D2D1::LayerParameters(D2D1::RectF(rc.right / 4, rc.bottom / 4, rc.right * 3 / 4, rc.bottom * 3 / 4)), layer.Get());

        // draw checkerboard
        const float squares = 8.0f;
        auto dx = rc.right / squares;
        auto dy = rc.bottom / squares;
        for (auto i = 0; i < squares; i++)
        {
            for (auto j = i % 2; j < squares; j += 2)
            {
                renderTarget->FillRectangle(D2D1::RectF(dx * i, dy * j, dx * (i + 1), dy * (j + 1)), colorBrush.Get());
            }
        }

        // draw fx (doesn't need input image)
        deviceContext->DrawImage(effect.Get());

        renderTarget->PopLayer();

        hr = renderTarget->EndDraw();
    }
    break;

    case WM_SIZE:
        if (renderTarget)
        {
            // resize render target
            RECT rc; GetClientRect(hwnd, &rc);
            renderTarget->Resize(D2D1::SizeU(rc.right - rc.left, rc.bottom - rc.top));

            // resize effect
            auto hr = effect->SetValue(D2D1_TURBULENCE_PROP_SIZE, D2D1::Point2F(rc.right, rc.bottom));
        }
        break;

    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;
    }
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}

int WINAPI WinMain(_In_ HINSTANCE hInstance, _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, _In_ LPSTR lpCmdLine, _In_ int nShowCmd)
{
    // init & create window
    WNDCLASSEX cls = { sizeof(WNDCLASSEX) };
    cls.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    cls.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    cls.hInstance = hInstance;
    cls.hCursor = LoadCursor(nullptr, IDI_APPLICATION);
    cls.lpszClassName = L"D2DDemoApp";
    RegisterClassEx(&cls);

    auto hwnd = CreateWindow(cls.lpszClassName, L"Effect + Layer", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 400, 400, nullptr, nullptr, hInstance, nullptr);
    ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_SHOWNORMAL);

    // create D2D factory
    ComPtr<ID2D1Factory> factory;
    auto hr = D2D1CreateFactory(D2D1_FACTORY_TYPE_SINGLE_THREADED, factory.GetAddressOf());

    // create render target & device context
    RECT rc;
    GetClientRect(hwnd, &rc);
    auto size = D2D1::SizeU(rc.right - rc.left, rc.bottom - rc.top);
    hr = factory->CreateHwndRenderTarget(D2D1::RenderTargetProperties(), D2D1::HwndRenderTargetProperties(hwnd, size), &renderTarget);
    hr = renderTarget->QueryInterface(deviceContext.GetAddressOf());

    // create fx & color
    hr = deviceContext->CreateEffect(CLSID_D2D1Turbulence, effect.GetAddressOf());
    hr = renderTarget->CreateSolidColorBrush(D2D1::ColorF(D2D1::ColorF::Orange), colorBrush.GetAddressOf());

    // force compute size-related resources
    SendMessage(hwnd, WM_SIZE, 0, 0);

    MSG msg;
    while (GetMessage(&msg, nullptr, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
}
```

If you run as is you should see this:

[image]

But you can play with the code and remove the effect (turbulence aka noise) and/ or the layer:

[image]

[image]
[image]